# Unhandled Promise Rejection is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

In my React Native App, I have a custom login facebook button :

```
<Button onPress={() => this.handleFacebookLogin()}>
  <Text>Login with Face</Text>
</Button>
```

And the handleFacebookLogin function :

```
 handleFacebookLogin () {
     LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
       function (result) {
         if (result.isCancelled) {
           console.log('Login cancelled')
         } else {
           console.log('Login success with permissions: ' + result.grantedPermissions.toString())
           AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
             (data) => {
               signInFacebookLoginInFirebase(data.accessToken)
               //this.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase(data.accessToken)
             }
           )
         }
       },
       function (error) {
         console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error)
         alert('Error at login, no network ?')
       }
     )
 }
```

But I get this error :

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 20): ReferenceError:
>   signInFacebookLoginInFirebase is not defined
>   TypeError: _this2.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase is not a function

TypeError: _this2.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase is not a function

And signInFacebookLoginInFirebase method :

```
   signInFacebookLoginInFirebase(facebookToken){
     const credential = Fb.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookToken);
     Fb.firebase
       .auth()
       .signInWithCredential(credential)
       .then(() => alert('Account accepted'))
       .catch((error) => alert('Account disabled'));
   }
```

Comment: so do you have a function called `signInFacebookLoginInFirebase` ?

Comment: Wrong line commented out?

Comment: I tried with "this" but don't work

Comment: change `function (result)` to `(result) =>` ... now `this` may well be correct, so you can use `this.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase` - perhaps? not clear from your disparate code fragments

Comment: It's working, thanks @JaromandaX, I upvote your answer if you post one

Comment: By the way, your code does not handle any (potential) rejection by either `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken` or `this.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase`

Comment: That solves the error you got, but you're receiving 'unhandled promise rejection' because you have no catch function set up for your promises so this error will show anytime something errors out inside of them

Comment: there is  a catch in `signInFacebookLoginInFirebase`, and also an onRejected for the `.then` for `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions` - the only potential uncaught rejection is for `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`

Comment: @Xero - see updated answer for (in my opinion) better rejection handling

Comment: Thank you, I will check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using arrow notation for your `.then` callback to `logInWithReadPermissions`, `this` will not be the context of your `signInFacebookLoginInFirebase` function

you use arrow notation in `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then` so that's good, now you just simply change

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
    function (result) {
```

to

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
    (result) => {
```

and then use the commented out

```
this.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase(data.accessToken);
```

To properly handle all potential rejections, I would recommend

```
handleFacebookLogin () {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends'])
    .then(result => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            console.log('Login cancelled');
        } else {
            console.log('Login success with permissions: ' + result.grantedPermissions.toString())
            return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
            .then(data => this.signInFacebookLoginInFirebase(data.accessToken));
        }
    // .catch chained from .then to handle all rejections
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
        alert('Error at login, no network ?');
    })
}
```